# How to check set is subset with same order in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, list, set, aggregate-functions

If i have one list/set in mongo db like as below

```
[a,a,c,b,b]
```

now i want check below set/list are exist in parent set

```
[a,b,c] false  because we have sequence a,c,b not a,b,c
[a,c,b] `true`   
[a,c] `true`
```

subset should be same order of parent set and in between of steps there are so many others steps but should always be same order....

Comment: I’ve just [edited your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/editing), improving either its formatting, or [its quality](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/02/05/suggested-edits-and-edit-review/) to help people understanding your question, and to help you to get an appropriate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following :

**$setIsSubset** aggregation pipeline operator of the mongodb

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/setIsSubset/

Comment: when i try subset ['a','b','c'] it should be false in my case because after b there is not doing c event....

but setissubset return true...

Comment: Document is below...

{
 "_id" : ObjectId("5c0e0ebd3b936af0b7a9f30f"),
 "set" : [
  "a",
  "a",
  "c",
  "b",
  "b"
 ]
}


db.test.aggregate([{$project:{"set":1,step_2:{$setIsSubset:[["a","b","c"],"$set"]}}}]).pretty();

Output should be false.....

Comment: You can refer this link : http://www.kamsky.org/stupid-tricks-with-mongodb/how-to-match-a-strict-subset-of-an-array-in-order
Hope this helps you.

Comment: yes i checked link and i found some mistake or ask additional that i post in comment in that website...

{ "_id" : 8, "actions" : [ 6, 8, 3, 8 ] }

this set will also true 6,3,8 is true for this